# How to recover access to GMail website?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail

I've been using GMail for years, suddenly today, I get this error message on just one computer when trying to access https://mail.google.com/mail/:

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
ReloadHide details
Google Chrome could not load the webpage because mail.google.com took too long to respond. The website may be down, or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection.
Check your Internet connection
Check any cables and reboot any routers, modems, or other network devices you may be using.
Allow Chrome to access the network in your firewall or antivirus settings.
If it is already listed as a program allowed to access the network, try removing it from the list and adding it again.
If you use a proxy server...
Check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server: Go to Applications > System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and deselect any proxies that have been selected.
```

Other computers on the same router do not have this issue.

I'm on Macintosh OS X Yosemite.  The above error is for Chrome, if I try that web address on Safari, I get a similar error:

[image]

All other web pages I try work, both http and https.  Even other Google products like calendar, drive, and maps work, just not GMail.  Based on what I read on websites trying to help with this issue, I tried removing all cookies, rebooting, and cleared my downloaded files, but nothing helped.

I'm at a loss of what is going on.  How can I restore access to GMail again?  Would upgrading to El Capitan help?  Can I try the IP address instead?  Not sure what IP would resolve for this site though.  Ping of gmail fails with request timeout:

[image]

Trying ip address as seen from ping to http://74.125.225.16/mail does not work either.  Ping on another computer on the same router gives: 216.58.216.5 and going to http://216.58.216.5/mail on the broken computer gives `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` whereas going to http://74.125.225.16/mail on a working computer does not work either.

---

Update: Now have discovered that a second MacBook Air, this one running OS X El Capitan, is experiencing the same issue.  Unclear when it started, since that laptop hadn't been used for a few days.

Here are my experiments today on the first broken MacBook Air.

```
ping mail.google.com => 74.125.225.16 => Request timeout for icmp_seq
```

Here are my experiments today on the second broken MacBook Air.

```
ping mail.google.com => 74.125.225.20 => Request timeout for icmp_seq
```

Change internet connection from home router to tethering phone over Verizon network and ping still returns the same address on each broken Mac, 74.125.225.16 and 74.125.225.20 respectively.

Go to the working MacBook Pro today on the home router network.

```
ping mail.google.com => 216.58.216.14 => successful pings.
```

On both the second and first broken MacBook Air

```
Going to http://74.125.225.16 => `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
Going to http://74.125.225.16/mail => `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
Going to http://74.125.225.20 => `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
Going to http://74.125.225.20/mail => `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
Going to http://216.58.216.14 => Goes to Google search home page.
Going to http://216.58.216.14/mail => `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
```

On the working MacBook Pro

```
Going to http://74.125.225.16 => Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host
Going to http://74.125.225.16/mail => Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host
Going to http://74.125.225.20 => Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host
Going to http://74.125.225.20/mail => Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host
Going to http://216.58.216.14 => Goes to Google search home page.
Going to http://216.58.216.14/mail => Goes to gmail.
```

Comment: Can you try with a freshly installed Firefox?

Comment: @Paul Updated question, ping is different on another computer on same router, using that other ip address doesn't fix issue on broken computer.

Comment: @dx486 We are using Chrome and Safari, both have the same issue, Firefox is not part of the reported issue.

Comment: There is only one explanations for this behavior. Your OS X machine is using a DNS server that can't resolve google.com.  Being unable to literally ping google.com is normal, it Is trivial, to configure your server not to respond to ping packets.

Comment: @Paul - Just because he gets an address does meant its the correct address.  Given I am doing pings against mail.google.com right now, I get back a IPv6 address, which I know Yosemite supports

Comment: Just because it resolves to something doesn't meant it's resolving to a Google address, just because the local cache knows what the IP address should be, does not mean it's resolving the path to the address

Comment: Only confusing matters honestly

Comment: @Ramhound Updated question details to try and clarify behavior.

Comment: @Paul Updated question details to try and clarify behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is definitely a DNS resolution problem for mail.google.com

I've been suffering from the exact same problem, and the solution was ....... an old entry in /etc/hosts hardcoding the IP for mail.google.com

I had put this entry years ago as a work around my ISP's dodgy DNS that were not able to resolve google.com half of the time.

One way to diagnose it was compare the result of the nslookup for mail.google.com in the terminal of my faulty machine, the same in my other working ones, and the result you get from an only NSLookup....... if they don't match you get the clue

So:
- try to switch to Goggle DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
- check for any entry in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2):

On my tests Gmail is unreachable with the IP address you also reported broken (`74.125.225.16`). I also cannot get reply to my pings to this address.

You should be able to access Gmail via [mail.google.com](http://mail.google.com) or [googlemail.com](http://googlemail.com), both resolves to the address: `216.58.212.37`. You reported this address as Google search page address. It is true if you directly enter this address to your browser, however when you ping mail.google.com or googlemail.com you will see that this is the IP address Gmail is using.

I think your problem is related to DNS. Check your DNS settings and if possible use a different DNS, e.g. OpenDNS or Google DNS.

In addition, please check your hosts file at `/private/etc/hosts` to see if there is any related entry. If you can find anything, disable (with a `#` in the beginning of the line) or remove those lines, flush your DNS cache and try again (of course make a backup of that file first).

You may use this command to flush your DNS cache:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: Issue was indeed /private/etc/hosts entry.